# What is java.util.Timer fixed-delay periodic task?

Tags: java

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class PeriodicTask {

 public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Main thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            System.out.print("Timer task invoked in millis: " +
                                             (System.currentTimeMillis()- start));
            System.out.println(" -- "  + Thread.currentThread());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("task finished "+(System.currentTimeMillis()
                                - start));
        }
    }, 1000,500);
 }
}
```

The output:

```
Main thread: Thread[main,5,main]
Timer task invoked in millis: 1000 -- Thread[Timer-0,5,main]
task finished 2001
Timer task invoked in millis: 2001 -- Thread[Timer-0,5,main]
task finished 3002
Timer task invoked in millis: 3002 -- Thread[Timer-0,5,main]
task finished 4002
Timer task invoked in millis: 4002 -- Thread[Timer-0,5,main]
......
```

According to the java.util.Timer docs the provided time period should separate each task execution. So I'm expecting each fished task and new invoked task should be separated by 500 millis e.g. between end of the first and start of the second task execution should be:

```
task finished 2001
Timer task invoked in millis: **2501** -- Thread[Timer-0,5,main]
```

Am I missing something?

I'm using JDK 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `period` that separates each task is not relative to the end of the task but rather to its beginning. The `Timer` will try to schedule the task again after the `period` has gone by. Except when the task is still running, it will be scheduled as soon as the previous task is complete.

In the example you gave you set a `Timer` with a `period` of `500ms`. You called `sleep()` inside the `run()` method for `1000ms`. This means that `Timer` wanted to schedule the task again after just half a second, but couldn't because the previous task still has another half second until it is completed.

Comment: your explanation is pretty much consistent with my output. I guess Java docs are very badly written. e.g. "In fixed-delay execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the actual execution time of the previous execution". Don't know what they are trying to say. The world "execution" is used four times in one sentence.

Comment: @Joe yeah. I checked the java docs and didn't really understand it either, so that's why I set up some tests and found this to be consistent. Also if it's not to much to ask could you mark this as correct.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help man!